# How to configure dotnet-tests-report in GitHub Actions?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have some experience with Azure Devops and I just got started with GitHub Actions.

My project includes automated tests which can be tested with [this action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/dotnet-tests-report).

However, I think I should be able to do the following:

1. Configure the test to build and run in Release mode.
2. Make a job fail if the tests fail.

I find it important to keep it simple so I prefer not to switch to the solution described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/building-and-testing-net#packaging-workflow-data-as-artifacts) as this would mean to create multiple actions and require my colleagues to download an artifact to view the test results.

How can I make these kind of nice test reports but still be able to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all described in the [action definition](https://github.com/zyborg/dotnet-tests-report/blob/master/action.yml):

```
[...]
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: use this action, test solution dir
        uses: zyborg/dotnet-tests-report@v1
        with:
          project_path: tests/My.Project.Tests
          report_name: my_project_tests
          report_title: My Project Tests
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          # If set to true, the build will fail if at least one test fails
          fail_build_on_failed_tests: true
          # the configuration passed to the msbuild process, such as `Release` or `Debug`.
          msbuild_configuration: Release
```

Comment: I'm using "github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" and get the error:
Invoke-WebRequest: /home/runner/work/_actions/zyborg/dotnet-tests-report/v1.4.4/action.ps1:149
Line |
 149 |      Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $hdr $url -Method Post -Body ($bdy | C …
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | {"message":"Bad
     | credentials","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest"}